# Rotate the marker according to the direction of the phone?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, android-animation

i display an arrow(marker) at my location on a google map view and i want to rotate the arrow according to the direction of the phone!

The marker when it rotates I think it should have a smooth movement from the position it was in the position it will be in! For example I hold the phone in N I will have 0 degrees so the arrow will be in the north. And when I move the phone 30 degrees to the right, it should have a smooth movement between them.

a)I have calculated Azimut angle using the sensor values from the magnetometer and acceleromet,
this angle represents the current direction of the device compass and magnetic N,and I tried to use it to rotate the marker that represents my location but I didn't succeed...
First time i calculated the angels:

```
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private final float[] accelerometerReading = new float[3];
    private final float[] magnetometerReading = new float[3];
  
    private final float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    private final float[] orientationAngles = new float[3];
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_maps);
      
        mSensorManager=(SensorManager)this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

       
    }
```

In the onSensorChanged method here we read what values ​​we take from the sensors:

```
 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
       if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        
            System.arraycopy(sensorEvent.values, 0, accelerometerReading,
                    0, accelerometerReading.length);
        } else if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            System.arraycopy(sensorEvent.values, 0, magnetometerReading,
                    0, magnetometerReading.length);
        }
        updateOrientationAngles();
    }
```

and method updateOrientationAngles(); contain:

```
 float azimuthInDegress;
    private void updateOrientationAngles() {
        // Update rotation matrix, which is needed to update orientation angles.
        // "rotationMatrix" now has up-to-date information.
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null,
                accelerometerReading, magnetometerReading);

        // "orientationAngles" now has up-to-date information.
        //contine cele 3 unghiuri
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationAngles);

        azimuthInDegress = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientationAngles[0])+360)%360;
        Log.i("Messages","orientationAngles:"+orientationAngles[0]);

    }
```

azimuthInDegress contains value that I think we are interested in to make the marker move;
And in onLocationonLocationChanged i put-->>

```
locationListener=new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

                mOurLocation=location;


                // Add a marker in Our Location and move the camera
               if(mOurLocationMarker!=null){
                   mOurLocationMarker.remove();
                   mMap.clear();
               }
                LatLng coor = new LatLng(mOurLocation.getLatitude(), mOurLocation.getLongitude());
                putOnTheMapMarkerUser(coor);


            }
        };
```

and the method putOnTheMapMarkerUser(coord) is:

```
  private void putOnTheMapMarkerUser(LatLng latLng){
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_me);//am convertit in BitmapDrawable
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();//convertitm in bitmap
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 90, 90, false);//aici scalam
        mOurLocationMarker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My position").flat(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mOurLocationMarker.setRotation(mHeading);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,18));
    }
```

As I said in the title, I want to make an arrow rotation depending on the direction of the phone, I think I managed to calculate the rotation angle but I didn't manage to make the marker animation have a smooth rotation ..

Do you have any ideas? I look forward to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This code fragment demonstrates rotating a marker to a target heading using a gradual rotation.  For demo purposes, this code uses the map click listener to add a marker and start its rotation (3 markers are added in demo):

```
    final float tgtHdg = 135.0F;  // bearing to stop rotation
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng pos) {
            // Add marker
            MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().position(pos);
            final Marker m = mMap.addMarker(mo);
            m.setTag(new Float(0.0));
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    float hdg = (float)m.getTag();
                    m.setRotation(hdg);
                    // change the 1.0 for amount of rotation (degrees) per update.
                    hdg += 1.0f;
                    m.setTag(new Float(hdg));
                    if (hdg < tgtHdg) {
                        // change the '50' (milliseconds) for faster/slower.
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);  // initial delay - can be 0 (milliseconds).
        }
    });
```

And result

[image]

Comment: Thx for you answer, and i try it. 